# SQL to catch incremental entries from a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a historic table that won't be updated with new inserts, and a have a view that everyday will be update with new inserts. So I need to know if my SQL is correct.

This SQL needs to get all entries that inside in `FATO_Proposta_Planilha` table (Table 1)
and to add the entries not similar that are in the `FATO_Proposta_View table` (Table 2).

So, this SQL must have all entries from Table 1 more all entries from Table 2 that are not repeated in the Table 1. Can you give a opinion about this SQL, please?

```
SELECT vw.[DescPac] [PA]
,vw.[DescRegional] [Regional]
,vw.[DescSuperintendencia] [Superintendencia]
,vw.[NUM_CPF_CNPJ] [Documento_Numero]
,pla.[Nome] [Nome]
,pla.[Produto] [Produto]
,pla.[Modalidade] [Modalidade]                    
,vw.[NUM_CONTRATO_CREDITO] [Contrato]
,vw.[DESC_FINALIDADE_OPCRED] [Finalidade]
,vw.[DATA_OPERACAO] [Data_operacao]
,pla.[Data_mov_entrada] [Data_mov_entrada]
,vw.[DATA_VENC_OPCRED] [Data_vencimento]
,vw.[VALOR_CONTRATO_OPCRED] [Valor_contrato]
,pla.[Processo_Lecon] [Processo_Lecon]
                    ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(pla.Origem, '') = ''
THEN  'Esteira Convencional'
ELSE  pla.Origem
END [Origem]

     FROM Proposta_View vw
     LEFT JOIN FATO_Proposta_Planilha pla
   ON vw.NUM_CONTRATO_CREDITO = pla.Contrato


UNION

 SELECT   [PA] [PA]
,[Regional] [Regional]
,[Superintendencia] [Superintendencia]
,[Documento_Numero] [Documento_Numero]
,[Nome] [Nome]
,[Produto] [Produto]
,[Modalidade] [Modalidade]
,[Contrato] [Contrato]
,[Finalidade] [Finalidade]
,[Data_operacao] [Data_operacao]
,[Data_mov_entrada] [Data_mov_entrada]
,[Data_vencimento] [Data_vencimento]
,[Valor_contrato] [Valor_contrato]
,[Processo_Lecon] [Processo_Lecon]
,CASE WHEN ISNULL(Origem, '') = ''
THEN  'Esteira Convencional'
ELSE  Origem
END [Origem]
```

Comment: [so] isn't for asking opinions; asking for them is explicitly off-topic. This is noted in the [tour] that you were prompted to take (and didn't).  In regards to if your SQL is correct; you can easily test that but we can't; we have no DML or DDL statements and no expected results. Though the above will get an error, as your bottom statement has no `FROM` attempts to reference lots of columns. Also, it's very odd that you define all your columns as then alias them with the same name, and *don't* at least use `{expression} AS {Alias}` or `{Alias} = {Expression}` syntax.

Comment: With respect, this statement makes no sense.  *a view that everyday will be updated with new inserts*.  Views don't contain any data themselves, only data from underlying tables.  It sounds like you have a historical table and a current table with similar structures. Please [edit] your question to clarify, or ask another. And, please avoid the word "opinion" in your question.

Comment: "...table that won't be updated with new inserts, and a have a view that everyday will be update with new inserts.." -- well... that means that there actually be INSERTs on the table every day.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only inserting rows through the view you can add an extra column with a `DEFAULT` value to distinguish the old rows from the new ones.

For example if you have a table `t` as:

```
create table t (a int primary key not null);

insert into t (a) values (123), (456);
```

You can add the extra column as:

```
alter table t add is_new int default 1;

update t set is_new = 0;

create view v as select a from t;
```

Then each insert through the view won't see that new column and will insert with value `1`.

```
insert into v (a) values (789), (444);
```

Then it's easy to find the new rows:

```
select * from t where is_new = 1;
```

Result:

```
 a    is_new 
 ---- ------ 
 444  1      
 789  1
```

Se running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b33c721e385f4794acae9f01a5e95c39).